# Adjustable paperclip path

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

In my on Rails project I have this setup for Paperclip gem, using the DB extension:

```
 # Image attachment and validations
  has_attached_file :image,
                    :storage => :database,
                    :url => "/:rails_root/public/system/projects/000/000/:id/original/:filename",
                    :path => "/:rails_root/public/system/projects/000/000/:id/original/:filename"
```

Now, the image gets this route:

```
/C:/Users...
```

If I get rid of the initial `/` I get `images/C:/Users...`. Any idea how to get just the rails_root without anything in front?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution here `config/initializers/paperclip.rb`

```
    Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.merge!({
  :storage => :database,
  :url => ":rails_root/public",
  :path => ":rails_root/public"
})
```